# Different formats of JSON responses on different servers

Tags: php, json, nginx, laravel-5

I'm using laravel and returning a json object for an API, with the following line:

```
Return \Response::json(array(
            'width' => $widget->widget->width,
            'height' => $widget->widget->height
        ));
```

When I test locally, with my regular laravel server (php -S), the response comes out like this:

```
{"width":2,"height":1}
```

When I test on my VPS using Nginx, the response comes out like this:

```
{"width":"2","height":"1"}
```

The adding of the double quotes didn't seem like a big deal at first but now it's killing some parts of my application. 
My question is: why this happens and how can I make it uniform? (preferrably both like the first one)

ps: I suppose it's a server difference but maybe it could be the PHP version or something else. The code is the exact same for both.

Comment: Are you fetching the values from MySQL? This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961870/laravel-returns-json-string-on-local-machine-but-integer-on-elastic-beanstalk-in

Comment: This doesn't answer why it's happening, but you can use Attribute casting (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) to help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can pass in JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK as an option

```
Response::json($data, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

**Solution 2**

Install MySQL native driver. `yum install php-mysqlnd` for Redhat based distros such as CentOS. For Debian based distros, you can use `apt-get` instead of `yum`.

**Reason for the instability**

Some database drivers return strings disregarding the field data type of int. Therefore, the property in your object is type of string, and treated by json_encode() as it is.